# How to store all connections to a WCF service?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

My WCF service uses callbacks. To be able to call all clients, I'm using something like this:

```
[ServiceBehavior (InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.PerSession)]
class Svc
{
    // stores all connections
    private static List<Svc> Connections = new List<Svc> ();

    // callback for this instance
    private ICallback Cb;

    public Svc ()
    {
        Cb = OperationContext.Current.GetCallbackChannel<ICallback> ();
        Connections.Add (this);
    }

    // ... lots of other code that uses or updates the list of connections
}
```

Is this the right way to do it?

I'm asking because I'm fighting with an apparent design problem in the above approach. I tried to move a lot of common code, including the `static List<Svc>` to a common base class that can be used by all my WCF services. But when deriving, this list is shared among all subclasses.

I then tried to avoid this undesirable sharing by making the base class generic (`Svc<T>`, meaning each subclass gets its own static members) but this leads to other annoyances and is not a clean design.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is the right approach of storing references to your clients to send callbacks to all of them. I don't store the CallbackChannel objects but the OperationContext instances in my service.

To your other question: You could extract the code to administrate the list of connected clients to a separate class and use an instance of that class in your service.

Answer (score 0):

**Use the Singleton pattern** when you need to store global state in a centralized manner.

In your case it could look like this:

```
public Svc()
{
    this.CallbackChannel = OperationContext.Current.GetCallbackChannel<ICallback>();

    // The static 'Instance' property returns the singleton
    SvcActiveInstanceContainer.Instance.Add(this);
}
```

**Related resources:**

- [Singleton Design Pattern](http://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/singleton)

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand how this is helping in any way? The issue with shared variables is not solved. And the service cannot be singleton to begin with (`PerSession`).